# Exoplayer throws Player is accessed on the wrong thread when calling experimentalSetOffloadSchedulingEnabled

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I'm new an `exoplayer` and want to use the `experimentalSetOffloadSchedulingEnabled` function.
My `exoplayer` is implemented like:

```
    DefaultRenderersFactory factory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(getApplicationContext())
            .setEnableAudioOffload(true);
    exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setLooper(Looper.myLooper())
            .setRenderersFactory(factory)
            .build();
```

In `onResume()` from `MainActivity` I set `exoPlayer.experimentalSetOffloadSchedulingEnabled(false);` which throws "Player is accessed on the wrong thread." exception on some devices.

```
exoPlayer.experimentalSetOffloadSchedulingEnabled(false);
```

How can I access exoplayers looper to set the `experimentalSetOffloadSchedulingEnabled` in the correct thread.

I do not know where `ConnectivityThread` comes from.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mediaapp.test/com.mediaapp.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Player is accessed on the wrong thread. 
Current thread: 'main'
Expected thread: 'ConnectivityThread'
See https://exoplayer.dev/issues/player-accessed-on-wrong-thread
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5312)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5351)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Thanks,
GGK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [exoplayer api doc](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.Builder.html#setLooper(android.os.Looper)), your exoplayer instance can only be called in thread set by `setLooper()`. `onResume` is usually called in the main thread. Is it possible that your exoplayer instance is sometimes built in a thread other than the main thread? Adding some logs to print out the current thread may help.

Comment: update OP. Thanks

Comment: @GGKstandsforUkraine It seems your ExoPlayer is created in that ConnectivityThread. Do that in the main thread will solve your problem : )

Comment: exoplayer is created in onCreate() in BackgroudAudioservice.class and services are running in main thread ...exoplayer.isPlaying() is called from different runnables

Comment: You were right, I was calling exoplayer in a thread. Thanks